# How to extract all repositories from GitHub given some criteria?

Tags: python, github-pages, github-api

I want to extract all GitHub repositories that have the following criteria:

1. written in Python
2. used the `numpy` package
3. created after 2015

Currently, I am using the following query:

```
https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/numpy%20in:name,description&python?language=python&per_page=50&page=1
```

But, every time I change the `page` parameter, I get the same repositories in the response. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories) says that you should use the `GET /search/repositories` endpoint, rather than `GET /legacy/repos/search`.

The following:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=numpy%20in:name,description&python?language=python&per_page=50&page=1
```

returns results that are paginated correctly.